# Get Topics from multiple Category and show top ten topics with responses in mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql, database, subquery

Hi friends i am listing topics in php which may be associated with multiple category

my db schema is

```
topics

topic_id
user_id
topic_name

category 

category_id
category_name


topic_category (for association)

tc_id
topic_id
category_id
```

topic_response // for results

```
tr_id
topic_id
response ( given in a form of 5 star rating so its in range of 1-5 always )
user_id
```

what i need to do is

**1st ) list top ten topics based on responses ya it will be based on count of responses**

i tried ->

```
select t.* ,count(tr.response) as votes from topics t , topic_response tr where t.topic_id=tr.topic_id group by tr.topic_id order by votes LIMIT 10
```

not working

**2nd) user will be shown list of topic . he can choose the category in which he wants that can be multiple too.**

for  example

if he  chooses  `category_id 1,2,3,4`  then topics listed in this category will be listed.

i have tried to

```
select t.* from topics t ,topic_category tc where tc.topic_id = t.topic_id and category_id IN (1,3,2,4) 
// not able to get idea on this i would prefer if i could do this in subquery since i also need to check if the user has already responded to that question .
```

**3) in case if i get a query working suppose .

from php side i will be getting an array of category_id from select multiple dropdown
like array(1,2,3,4)

so i was thinking how will make this query accept  category id

in form of  `category_id IN (1,3,2,4)` in mysql query**

**can i directly pass an array like

`category_id IN ($ids)` where `$ids` is an array**

i am a newbie in mysql please help me
you help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question:

You have to use LEFT JOIN and match (response's topic id row) to (topic's id) then count(response's topic id) and GROUP everything by (response's topic id).

for example:

## Responses Table = responses

response_id

topic_id

response_message

## Topics Table = topics

id

title

## content

The query is

SELECT topics.title,topics.content,COUNT(responses.topic_id) AS count FROM topics
LEFT JOIN responses ON topics.id = responses.topic_id GROUP BY count LIMIT 10

## For question 2:

1. You can try using AND ( IN 1 OR 2 OR 3 OR 4
2. You can try using BETWEEN 1 AND 4
3. WHERE(category_id>=1&&category_id<=4)